# Ember.js: controllerFor x needs

Tags: ember.js

I'm having a problem with `controllerFor`, and I found this pull request which describes deprecating `controllerFor`:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1896

So this means that I can't use `controllerFor`? And if the answer is "not", why does the Ember.js docs still talk about using `controllerFor`, as seen here:

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/

Answer (score 11):

The [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1896) you linked to deprecates the `controllerFor` method in `Ember.Controller`.  You can and should use `controllerFor` within the router, which is how it is used in [the guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/) you referenced.

Instead of using `controllerFor` from controllers you are supposed to instead use the needs mechanism, which is discussed in [this guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

Comment: The link to the needs mechanism (last one) is dead.